# Filtering issues with JSON

Tags: json, jq

I can't use environment variables inside a string in jmespath. Using a wildcard could have also worked but it didn't work in my case either. Any leads on this issue would be appreciated thanks!

```
aws logs describe-log-groups | jq -r --arg CLUSTER_NAME "$EKS_CLUSTER_NAME" '.logGroups[] | select(.logGroupName == '/aws/eks/$CLUSTER_NAME/cluster')'
```

Output:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.logGroups[] | select(.logGroupName == /aws/eks//cluster)
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: You are using jq, not JMESPath, those are two different query libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

- Your inner `jq` quotes conflict with the outer shell quotes. Replace the inner ones with double quotes `"`, which is the way to use string literals in `jq`.
- To include a variable's value inside a string in `jq` you would either add up the parts (e.g. using `+` as in `".." + $var + ".."`), or use string interpolation `"..\($var).."`

Try

```bash
jq -r --arg CLUSTER_NAME "$EKS_CLUSTER_NAME" '
  .logGroups[] | select(.logGroupName == "/aws/eks/\($CLUSTER_NAME)/cluster")
'
```